# Is it possible to use an ActiveX-Component within an ASP.NET-WebAPI Project hosted in an Azure WebApp?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, activex

I have a little ASP.NET WebAPI-project using an ActiveX-Component (UI-less just plain functionality).

As I wanted to host the thing on Azure, I were quite sure, that I won't be able to register the ActiveX-DLL on the underlying OS, so registration-free COM is being used through the SXS-manifest-mechanism described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms973913(v=msdn.10) and here http://blog.functionalfun.net/2012/09/a-quick-guide-to-registration-free-com.html.

This all works like a charm on my local IIS but on Azure it seems like I can't call the native method CreateActCtxW from kernel32.dll via Dll-Import, which I have to do (amongst other things), to inform the system to load my app-manifest. The call succeeds, but delivers a -1.

Marshal.GetLastWin32Error says: "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail"

I tried to run sxstrace on the underlying OS, which gives me an "Access denied".

So my question is: Can an ActiveX-DLL be registered on the underlying OS of an Azure WebApp **or** is there any possibility to get the registration-free COM Mechanism working?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://oren.codes/2018/02/25/registration-free-com-with-azure-app-services/